# Different text colors for actionbar

Tags: android

I am developing for android lollipop and have an actionbar with the text color as white therefore I need the textColorPrimary == white

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light">
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#ffffff</item>
</style>
```

However, I want the rest of the app's textColor to be black especially the alert dialogs because the white text can't be seen on the white background.

How can I have the actionbar to have white text while everything else black?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple way is to just inherit from `DarkActionBar` theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#000</item>
</style>
```

A bit more complex and customizable way would be to create you own `actionBarTheme`:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light">
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#000</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTheme">@style/ActionBarTheme</item>
</style>
<style name="ActionBarTheme">
    <item name="android:actionBarPopupTheme">@android:style/ThemeOverlay.Material.Light</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#fff</item>
</style>
```